# Store list of users who have voted and stop re-voting

Tags: sql, rdbms, database

I want to store the list of users who have voted on an article.

Also want to avoid same user from re-voting again.

What I have now is just use article_id to reference this way,

VOTING : article_id | user_id

ARTICLE : article_id | article_text  | rating

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Define `efficient`. Is this solution inefficient for you?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: how does this question related to SPs?

Comment: So that I can figure out what efficient is ...

Comment: A more quicker way, will storing all users in a single cell with commas separating them be more efficient than having a row for each user in VOTING row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database is right the only thing is that the TABLE VOTING should have the pair (article_id | user_id) as unique.
In that way will be impossible to vote twice the same article to the user.